# What are the effects of double quotes in echo statements?

Tags: bash, quoting, echo

When writing a Bash script that contains messages for the user, I can write

```
echo Processing files...
```

or

```
echo "Processing files..."
```

In this and many other cases, the output will be the same. So when do I actually need double quotes, and when may they be unnecessary?

I understand that

```
echo This    is     my      sentence.
```

and

```
echo "This    is     my      sentence."
```

will produce different outputs (single space between words in first case, spacing retained in second case), but are there other reasons to use double quotes? Or *not* to use double quotes?

(I realize that single quotes have a different effect; this question is specifically about *double* quotes.)

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/117549

Comment: Use quotes and also curly braces in `${vars}` when the output is the same. Less chance that it will break after future modifications.

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of reasons, but the main ones:

- better control over the inclusion of whitespace (which you noticed)
- partial protection against unexpected shell expansion, e.g., of glob characters `*` and `?`

Comment: Though ` (backtick), $, and \ (escape) will still be recognized in double quotes.

Reference: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html

Comment: TLDP is known as a poor information resource. I found an error in the page linked above.  And it refers to the ``\`` character as “escape”, which is not really standard and is especially confusing when it also uses “escape” as a verb.

Answer (score 0):

There is an important difference between double-quotes and single-quotes here. The double quotes will interpolate variables inside the quoted string (as will not quoting at all); single quotes will not do so.

Comment: agreed, but OP asked about double-quotes, which do have their place in scripting.  I marked it to close as well, but this is one of those cut/paste magnets...